# Privileges elevation on DSM7

Tags: synology

We’re editor of backup software, and migration from DSM6 to DSM7 has increased security: now declaring a package running with root privileges is forbidden (except for those written by Synology itself ).
Backup software supposes a full access to all filesystem and with DSM7 I can’t find any way to do so:

- `"defaults": { "run-as": "root" }` (in `conf/privileges`) is not allowed anymore
- requesting membership to `root` or `administrators` groups is not allowed either

When asking on Synology forum, I am redirected to developpers page or DSM developper manual .

I am currently out of ideas; I may have missed something somewhere, so is there any way to ask for privileges elevation on DSM7?

Answer (score 0):

See the second post in this link. Looks like you may need to request some kind of token from synology.

https://forum.resilio.com/topic/72409-synology-dsm-7-beta-current-third-party-incompatible/

Comment: Unfortunately, this requires a manual operation on the target NAS, the purpose here is to help developpers during package development, but won’t help for release (you can’t ask all users to manually place a file in `/var/packages`).  
And welcome to StackOverflow, by the way 